# How can be Focus() mocked in moq c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, testing, moq

I am using moq to mock application.
Everything seems to work but I dont know how to moq focus on button for example.
Lets say I have in xaml.cs

```
SomeButton.Focus();
```

How can this be mocked in moq?
In application I can see focus on button but in mocked testing version I cant.

Comment: What would be the programmatic effect in your workflow, when that button is focused? Color change?

Comment: Nothing. Button is focused when new small windows in center of screen is opened.
Ou yes. There is border around button.

Comment: And why do you need to mock it? Why can't you just call `.Focus()`? I am trying to grasp the problem you are facing.

Comment: Well I am pretty beginner sorry If I misunderstood something. I need to mock focus functionality. Because in test GUI I cant see focus happen in production GUI I am able to see it.